# Rspec problem mocking model in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, mocking, rspec

I set up a controller which handles omniauth authentications which are worked into a custom built authentication system.  i am trying to test the logic for how authentications are handled (ex: if user already has/does not have account, if user is/isn't currently logged in, etc.).  as such i have a Authorization model and a authorizations controller.  The action to create a authorization  has this general outline:

```
class AuthorizationsController < ApplicationController 

  def create  
    omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    authorization = Authorization.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
    if authorization
      # Authorization already established, log in user
    elsif current_user
      # User is logged in but wants to add another omniauth authentication
    else
      # Create user and associate them with omniauth authentication
    end
  end

end
```

I am trying to test this logic in Rspec but have been having issues.  Heres is what I am working with in my spec:

```
describe AuthorizationsController do
  render_views

  describe "POST 'create'" do

    describe "with an already existing authorization" do

      it "should log the user in" do
        @authmock = mock_model(Authorization)
        Authorization.should_receive(:find_by_provider_and_uid).and_return(@authmock)
        post :create, :provider => 'twitter'
        current_user?(@authmock.user).should == true
        response.should redirect_to(root_path)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am under the impression that this should assign my mocked Authorization model (@authmock) to the local variable authorization in my controller when the assignment call is made, thus making 'if authorization' return true.  However whenever I true to run this spec I get this error:

```
Failures:

  1) AuthorizationsController POST 'create' with an already existing authorization should log the user in
     Failure/Error: post :create, :provider => 'twitter'
     NoMethodError:
       You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
       You might have expected an instance of Array.
       The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
     # ./app/controllers/authorizations_controller.rb:5:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/authorizations_controller_spec.rb:16:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Can anyone enlighten me as to what I am doing wrong here?

**Edit:**

since the question was raised as to whether or not the assignment of omniauth was causing issues, I commented out that line to see what would happen and got the following error:

```
  1) AuthorizationsController POST 'create' with an already existing authorization should log the user in
     Failure/Error: post :create, :provider => 'twitter'
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `omniauth' for #<AuthorizationsController:0xb41809c>
 # ./app/controllers/authorizations_controller.rb:5:in `create'
 # ./spec/controllers/authorizations_controller_spec.rb:16:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

which tells me that the problem is with the mock or stub as the find_by_provider_and_uid function is still being evaluated and is not stubbed when the test runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you specing

```
current_user?(@authmock.user).should == true
```

or

```
response.should redirect_to(root_path)
```

I think that first expectation should not be tested here, because you've mocked 'if authorization' block, so you should spec what happens then!

Comment: point noted.  problem is though that the test never gets to this point as it fails at the line 'authorization = Authorization.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])'

Comment: Wierd ... Looks like it didn't stub method and tries to evaluate real find_by_provider_and_uid method with omniauth hash which is null in your case, right? omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']

Comment: as far as i can tell yea that seems to be the issue

Comment: Ahhh ... request.env is null here! That looks like problem

Comment: i dont believe that is the issue as the local variable just gets set to nil, which shouldnt be a problem.  the error gets thrown at line 5 too, which means that the assignment to request.env goes through fine.  i did however comment that line out just to see what happens and ill post that in an edit

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough in previous comment. I meant request.env is null, so there's problem when treating it as a Hash env['omniauth.auth']. Also I didn't understand what happend when you commented out 'omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
' line?

Comment: ah thank you therein lies the problem.  i was under the impression that the stub would cause the hash provided in the arguments to be ignored but that is clearly not the case.  looks like i have some more stubbing/mocking to do to get this fully operable :-X